# Which are main technical reasons to switch to Lion?

Tags: macos

Everywhere I just read posts and questions about how to make lion like snow leopard.
So... Why not keeping snow leopard, at least while lion's "young"?
Are there any technical / cosmetic reasons for the switch?

Comment: I'd say that depends a lot on what you use your Mac for. Software developers will have different reasons to switch than graphics designers or casual couch surfers.

Comment: I'd ignore anything that says "Make x look like <previous version>!". It's mostly people who don't like change.

Comment: Rather than calling for a large discussion about anything/everything that changed, is there a specific problem / requirements you have with this upgrade decision you face? (what criteria will make one answer the _right_ answer to this question.)

Answer (score 2):

Lion's improved security is worth a mention. Don't get me wrong, Lion still has its share of security issues (see [LDAP](http://www.infoworld.com/t/data-security/month-old-mac-os-x-lion-bug-lets-users-bypass-ldap-sans-password-170768) and [enterprise updates](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/08/08/mac_security_risk/)).  But Apple's inclusion of [sandboxing](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars/9#sandboxing), [full hard disk encryption](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars/13), and [a better ASLR](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/07/21/mac_os_x_lion_security/) goes a long way to reducing exposure to a wide variety of attacks.

Comment: I second this with a quote: “I generally tell Mac users that if they care about security, they should upgrade to Lion sooner rather than later, and the same goes for Windows users, too.” http://goo.gl/5S2LO

Answer (score 1):

There are no "technical reasons" per se. I'll quickly list my pros/cons but they are definitely personal.

**1. Pros**

- The uppgrade is pretty smooth and straightforward.
- It really does have a nicer 'look and feel'
- Most of the applications you can be using are already Lion Compatible
- It's the cheapest OS you can find

**2. Cons**

- If you use XCode you'll **HAVE** to reinstall a new version (4.1.1)
  (and that honestly is a big hitch which i didn't know about)
- The scrollbars !! : they are switched at first (up is down) but can
  be reversed and they are now iPhone like which is still annoying when you use a black background app that didn't change the scrollbar color. (basically you don't see them)

There could be much more things to say but [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars) did the best review you can find on the web.

I personally made the leap and really not regretting it so far.

Answer (score 1):

The principal compelling reason for upgrading to any new operating system version always comes down to the applications you want to run. When you find a new application, or a newer version of an older application, that you want to run, and you learn that this version of the application *requires* the newer operating system, that's when you want to consider upgrading.

I upgraded to Lion early because I'm a professional technical support technician, and I have to train myself be familiar with Lion when my clients start calling for help using Lion. If I were not a professional support technician, I would wait a lot longer to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Lion does have a lot of new Language features for those who need them:

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/07/os-x-107-lion-adds-major-new-language.html